# What are the downsides to using dependency injection?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection

I'm trying to introduce dependency injection (DI) as a pattern here at work and one of our lead developers would like to know: What, if any, are the **downsides** to using the [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern?

Note I'm looking here for an, if possible, exhaustive list, not a subjective discussion on the topic.

---

**Clarification**: I'm talking about the dependency injection *pattern* (see [this article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) by Martin Fowler), *not* a specific framework, whether XML-based (such as [Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework)) or code-based (such as [Guice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guice)), or "self-rolled".

---

Some great further discussion / ranting / debate is going on the [Reddit's subreddit */r/programming*](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/fir4j/what_are_the_downsides_to_using_dependency/).

Comment: It might be a good idea to specify whether we're supposed to be discussing DI itself or a specific type of tool that supports it (XML-based or not).

Comment: What's the difference between DI as a pattern and a specific framework? mind explain?

Comment: the difference is that I'm NOT looking for answers that only apply to specific frameworks, such as "XML sucks". :) I'm looking for answers that apply to the concept of DI as outlined by Fowler here: http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: I see no downsides at all to DI in general (constructor, setter or method). It decouples and simplifies with no overhead.

Comment: @kissaki well apart from the setter inject stuff. Best to make objects that are usable at construction. If you don't believe me, just try adding another collaborator to an object with 'setter' injection, you will get a NPE for sure....

Comment: [In Defense of Service Locator](http://bayou.io/draft/In_Defense_of_Service_Locator.html)

Comment: All the convoluted frameworks are the downside. "Register your container here", "Dont touch it over there", "you didnt create that instance using the magical, non-documented pattern required for this type of application (wpf)".. leading to hours wasted figuring out why a binding is not working.  If anyone can make a sane one that just makes the objects when needed, and is predictable, I would probably pay money for it.

Comment: @Epaga Implementing a design pattern without `class` syntax, would be a basic approach to clarify such questions. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45205564/3317808) is one example implementation of DI.Using English literature to answer such questions, is always their own interpretation and nothing else.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

A couple of points:

- DI increases complexity, usually by increasing the number of classes since responsibilities are separated more, which is not always beneficial
- Your code will be (somewhat) coupled to the dependency injection framework you use (or more generally how you decide to implement the DI pattern)
- DI containers or approaches that perform type resolving generally incur a slight runtime penalty (very negligible, but it's there)

Generally, the benefit of decoupling makes each task simpler to read and understand, but increases the complexity of orchestrating the more complex tasks.

Comment: - Separation of classes reduces complexity. Many classes don't make an application complex. 

- Your should only have a dependency at to your DI framework at the application-root.

Comment: We're humans; our short term memory is limited and cannot handle many <xxx> simultaneously. It's the same for classes as it is for methods, functions, files, or any construct you use to develop your program.

Comment: @Havard S:  Yes, but 5 really complex classes is not simpler than 15 simple ones.  The way to decrease complexity is to reduce the working set required by the programmer working on the code - complex, highly interdependent classes do not accomplish that.

Comment: @kyoryu I think we all agree on that. Keep in mind that _complexity is not the same as coupling_. Decreasing coupling can increase complexity. I'm really not saying that DI is a bad thing because it increases the number of classes, I'm highlighting the potential downsides associated with it. :)

Comment: basically it decreases the complexity of each individual building block, but increases the number of building blocks used to build the wall.

Comment: @Havard S:  Fair 'nuff.  Part of it is also how you define complexity - I generally define it as the minimum working set required by the programmer.

Comment: +1 for "DI increases complexity"  That's true in DI and beyond.  (Almost) any time we increase flexibility, we're going to increase complexity.  It's all about balance, which begins with knowing the upsides and downsides.  When people say, 'there are no downsides,' it's a sure indicator that they haven't fully understood the thing yet.

Comment: Yeah.  Today I ditched a major feature in about five minutes, since all I had to do was delete a few classes and modify my object graph.  Since no actual logic was changed, it was really easy to do with high confidence, and the compiler errors from the missing object told me what needed changing.  Man, that complexity sure bit me in the ass!

Comment: To build on what @Robert said, DI removes a little complexity in the form of wiring dependencies from many classes and centralizes it. It also makes every test less complex. The new place that does wiring may be somewhat complex but overall DI should greatly reduce complexity. If you think that DI increases complexity, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Eeh? I feel like everyone is getting what DI is wrong. DI does not need a framework. There’s no overhead. Also, if you already have sufficiently decoupled code (you hopefully do!) using DI will not add any more classes at all. It’s just how you pass dependencies to objects. With DI you will pass them to the object (on construction, setter, or method) instead of hard-coded in the class. This should not produce overhead nor complexity. It simplifies and decouples.

Comment: @Kissaki : Thanks ! I was thinking *I* got DI wrong because I'm only passing dependancies, and not using a framwork ;)

Comment: @Håvard S : I agree with kyoryu point of view : when you work on a class and it's decoupled, you need to remember much less stuff : you know the classes you're working with and you know their contracts. You don't care at all for the state of this little private member you added 1 year ago, which is the case when you work with monolithic classes, or even worse, when you use stateful singletons !

Comment: You might as well argue that breaking long methods up into short ones increases complexity.

Comment: You always had that complexity there **inherent in your problem**.  When designing with Composition in mind you're forced to think about that complexity upfront and decided how much to solve now, how much to punt on, how much to make open ended, etc.  That's not to say Composition (DI) is the only way to solve the problem, but it's better to face the complexity head on **now**, instead of in production when you realize you modeled everything wrong, but hey the DB calls are really quick!

Comment: `When people say, 'there are no downsides,' it's a sure indicator that they haven't fully understood the thing yet.` that's a baseless claim - downsides can only exist when compared to something. The only downside of well-executed DI compared to traditional spaghetti is "it does not provide as much job security"

Comment: Too many upvotes here. The real answer is the Andy Peck's one below (for your convenience: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4988337/414058). The greatest downside of dependency injection is that **it converts a strongly-typed language into a dynamic language**, and brings along all bad sides of dynamic languages: no IDE automation, errors pushed to runtime, inability to tell if a given registration is used or not (hard to keep code clean). It's counter-productive to select a language because it's statically checked, then select any reflection-based approach for a major control flow aspect.

Answer (score 202):

The same basic problem you often get with object oriented programming, style rules and just about everything else. It's possible - very common, in fact - to do too much abstraction, and to add too much indirection, and to generally apply good techniques excessively and in the wrong places.

Every pattern or other construct you apply brings complexity. Abstraction and indirection scatter information around, sometimes moving irrelevant detail out of the way, but equally sometimes making it harder to understand exactly what's happening. Every rule you apply brings inflexibility, ruling out options that might just be the best approach.

The point is to write code that does the job and is robust, readable and maintainable. You are a software developer - not an ivory tower builder.

**Relevant Links**

*[The Inner-Platform Effect](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Inner-Platform_Effect.aspx)*

*[Don’t Let Architecture Astronauts Scare You](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000018.html)*

---

Probably the simplest form of dependency injection (don't laugh) is a parameter. The dependent code is dependent on data, and that data is injected in by the means of passing the parameter.

Yes, it's silly and it doesn't address the object-oriented point of dependency injection, but a functional programmer will tell you that (if you have first class functions) this is the only kind of dependency injection you need. The point here is to take a trivial example, and show the potential problems.

Let’s take this simple traditional function. C++ syntax isn't significant here, but I have to spell it somehow...

```cpp
void Say_Hello_World ()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

I have a dependency I want to extract out and inject - the text "Hello World". Easy enough...

```cpp
void Say_Something (const char *p_text)
{
  std::cout << p_text << std::endl;
}
```

How is that more inflexible than the original? Well, what if I decide that the output should be Unicode. I probably want to switch from *std::cout* to *std::wcout*. But that means my strings then have to be of *wchar_*t, not of *char*. Either every caller has to be changed, or (more reasonably), the old implementation gets replaced with an adaptor that translates the string and calls the new implementation.

That's maintenance work right there that wouldn't be needed if we'd kept the original.

And if it seems trivial, take a look at this real-world function from the Win32 API...

*[CreateWindowExA function (winuser.h)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*

That's 12 "dependencies" to deal with. For example, if screen resolutions get really huge, maybe we'll need 64-bit co-ordinate values - and another version of CreateWindowEx. And yes, there's already an older version still hanging around, that presumably gets mapped to the newer version behind the scenes...

*[CreateWindowA macro (winuser.h)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*

Those "dependencies" aren't just a problem for the original developer - everyone who uses that interface has to look up what the dependencies are, how they are specified, and what they mean, and work out what to do for their application. This is where the words "sensible defaults" can make life much simpler.

Object-oriented dependency injection isn't any different in principle. Writing a class is an overhead, both in source-code text and in developer time, and if that class is written to supply dependencies according to some dependent objects specifications, then the dependent object is locked into supporting that interface, even if there's a need to replace the implementation of that object.

None of this should be read as claiming that dependency injection is bad - far from it. But any good technique can be applied excessively and in the wrong place. Just as not every string needs to be extracted out and turned into a parameter, not every low-level behaviour needs to be extracted out from high-level objects and turned into an injectable dependency.

Comment: Dependency injection does not have any of those drawbacks. It only changes the way your pass dependencies to objects, which does not add complexity nor inflexibility. Quite the contrary.

Comment: @Kissaki - yes, it changes the way you pass your dependencies. And you have to write code to handle that passing of dependencies. And before doing that, you have to work out which dependencies to pass, define them in a way that makes sense to someone who didn't code the dependent code, etc. You can avoid run-time impact (e.g. using policy parameters to templates in C++), but that's still code you have to write and maintain. If it's justified, it's a very small price for a big reward, but if you pretend there's no price to pay that just means you'll be paying that price when there's no gain.

Comment: @Kissaki - as for inflexibility, once you have specified what your dependencies are, you are locked into that - other people have written dependencies to inject according to that spec. If you need a new implementation for the dependent code which needs slightly different dependencies - tough, you're locked in. Time to start writing some adaptors for those dependencies instead (and a bit more overhead and another layer of abstraction).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this example, if you consider overloading. To output the literal "Hello World", we use the () signature. To output an 8-bit string, use the (char) signature. To output unicode, the overload (wchar_t). Obviously, in this case, (wchar_t) is the one that the others call behind the scenes. Not much code rewriting needed there. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ingredient_15939 - yes, this is a simplified toy example. If you were really doing this, you'd just use overloading rather than an adapter as the cost of duplicating the code is less than the cost of the adapter. But note that duplicating code is generally a bad thing, and using adapters to avoid duplicating code is another good technique (that can sometimes be used too much and in the wrong places).

Comment: I get your point. However, this kind of issue may indicates an abuse of abstraction. According to wikipedia: 

`A good abstraction will generalize that which can be made abstract; while allowing specificity where the abstraction breaks down and its successful application requires customization to each unique requirement or problem.`

Comment: I like the idea and the example you are giving, but I think it is misleading. Your original function has not dependency, they you are inserting one with DI. You should really compare a function that gets the value from somewhere (like a getter function) and a parameter passing, otherwise the comparison isn't fair. It would also be maintenance work to change the getter function if you wanted to change the text to unicode. Since the dependency is typically used more than it is given, the maintenance should actually be smaller for DI than normal dependency management.

Comment: @FrancescoPasa - The point isn't to advocate another form of dependency management - the point is to not have dependency management issues just because "DI is awesome!!!", but only if needed. If DI is provided even though it's unnecessary, it's a failure of encapulation - what should be a fully encapsulated implementation detail has been exposed to the caller in the form of that dependency, so the caller can be broken if it changes. A fully encapsulated implementation detail cannot cause that breakage by definition. The trade-off - encapsulated internals also can't be controlled by the caller.

Comment: I understand your point and fully agree, however it's more an issue with dependency versus encapsulation that something that has to do with Dependency Injection.

Comment: but in object oriented code, the whole idea is to pass messages around, so the "every caller" drawback you have is actually nullified by polymorphism - pass in a different version of that dependency that honors the interface.

i think your example being chosen poorly leads to a false conclusion.

Answer (score 82):

Here's my own initial reaction: Basically the same downsides of any pattern.

- it takes time to learn
- if misunderstood it can lead to more harm than good
- if taken to an extreme it can be more work than would justify the benefit

Comment: Why it takes time to learn? I thought it makes things simple compared with ejb.

Comment: This seems hand-wavy considering you don't want a subjective discussion. I suggest building (collectively, if necessary) a realistic example for examination. Building a sample *without* DI would be a good starting point. Then we could challenge it w.r.t. to requirement changes and examine the impact. (This is extremely convenient for me to suggest, by the way,  as I'm about to go to bed.)

Comment: This really needs some examples to back it up, and having taught dozens of people DI I can tell you that it really is a very simple concept to learn and to start putting into practice.

Comment: The only thing I'd say is that it has taken time to learn how to think "in DI" - it's a different (and better) way of approaching design. No longer do I let classes create and fetch their own dependencies. The object tree is built from leaf to root rather than vice versa. That takes a little getting used to. That's what I meant with taking time to learn.

Comment: I don't really consider DI a pattern.  It (coupled with IoC) are really more of a programming model - if you fully follow them, your code looks a lot more Actor-like than "typical" pseudo-procedural OO.

Comment: +1 I'm using Symfony 2, the DI is all over the user code, is exausting just using it.

Comment: I don't really consider DI / IOC a design pattern as much as I would consider it an Anti-Pattern. That is unless it is used sparingly where really appropriate. Kind of like a singleton pattern - to be used sparingly and only where it adds real value. Unfortunately these days we see entire frameworks with DI / IOC as the core. Magic - its auto injected but hey what exactly did we inject and how did it get there, who knows, who cares - really bad design.

Answer (score 48):

The biggest "downside" to Inversion of Control (not quite DI, but close enough) is that it tends to remove having a single point to look at an overview of an algorithm.  That's basically what happens when you have decoupled code, though - the ability to look in one place is an artifact of tight coupling.

Comment: But surely that "downside" is because of the nature of the problem we are solving, decoupling it so we can easily change the implementation means there is no one place to look at, and what relevance is it being able to look at it?  The only case I can think is in debugging and the debugging environment should be able to step into the implementation.

Comment: This is why the word "downside" was in quotes :)  Loose coupling and strong encapsulation preclude "one place to see everything," kind of by definition.  See my comments on Havard S's response, if you get the feeling that I'm against DI/IoC.

Comment: I agree (I even voted you up). I was just making the point.

Comment: @vickirk: The downside I guess is that it is hard for a human to comprehend. Decoupling things increases complexity in the sense that it is harder for humans to understand, and take longer to comprehend fully.

Comment: If we agree the poster meant IoC and not DI, then I would go as far as to say that this is the only drawback. Hopefully tools like [Code Bubbles](http://www.cs.brown.edu/people/spr/codebubbles) will make viewing loosely coupled algorithms a better experience.

Comment: Since DI leads to decoupling, and non-DI leads to coupling. You can argue decoupling has some downsides compared to coupling, which is exactly losing the ability to look at an overview of an algorithm in a single place. In that case, I would say metaphorically, to be human there're downsides, because we only have a limited brain to handle the nature of the complexity.

Comment: On the contrary, one advantage of DI is that you can look at the constructor of an individual class, and work out instantly what classes it depends on (i.e. what classes needs to do its work). This is much harder for other code, as the code can create classes willy-nilly.

Comment: On the contrary @Contango - One advantage of DI is the complete obfuscation of application logic flow especially in non trivial applications. Sometimes to the point where code obfuscation (for copy protection) is not even required anymore simply cause no one can figure out what was injected, how it was injected and where it came from. How exactly would you debug into a DI injected constructor and trace the logic of how and where the dependencies were created, etc...

Comment: @tcwicks You do have a point, a poorly architected DI application does not magically become easy to understand. However, a well architected DI application is great to work with. To answer your question, if you want to debug in C#, I find that putting a breakpoint anywhere, then looking at the call stack to see how the code got there, answers most of my questions most of the time. And, adding "ToString" overrides to summarize the state of each class on a debugger mouse hover is rather useful as well.

Comment: I will say that the use of some DI containers can often lead to applications where determining what is constructed can become much, much harder.  DI containers are not always a great solution.  I actually prefer "raw" DI in most cases.

Answer (score 46):

I have been using Guice (Java DI framework) extensively for the past 6 months. While overall I think it is great (especially from a testing perspective), there are certain downsides. Most notably:

- **Code can become harder to understand.** Dependency injection can be used in very... creative... ways. For example I just came across some code that used a custom annotation to inject a certain IOStreams (eg: @Server1Stream, @Server2Stream). While this does work, and I'll admit has a certain elegance, it makes understanding the Guice injections a prerequisite to understanding the code.
- **Higher learning curve when learning project.** This is related to point 1. In order to understand how a project that uses dependency injection works, you need to understand both the dependency injection pattern and the specific framework. When I started at my current job I spent quite a few confused hours groking what Guice was doing behind the scenes.
- **Constructors become large.** Although this can be largely resolved with a default constructor or a factory.
- **Errors can be obfuscated.** My most recent example of this was I had a collision on 2 flag names. Guice swallowed the error silently and one of my flags wasn't initialized.
- **Errors are pushed to run-time.** If you configure your Guice module incorrectly (circular reference, bad binding, ...) most of the errors are not uncovered during compile-time. Instead, the errors are exposed when the program is actually run.

Now that I've complained. Let me say that I will continue to (willingly) use Guice in my current project and most likely my next. Dependency injection is a great and incredibly powerful pattern. But it definitely can be confusing and you will almost certainly spend some time cursing at whatever dependency injection framework you choose.

Also, I agree with other posters that dependency injection can be overused.

Comment: I don't understand why people don't make  a bigger deal of "Errors are pushed to run-time" for me that's a deal breaker, static typing and compile time errors are the greatest gift given to developers, I wouldn't throw them away for anything

Comment: @RichardTingle , IMO during the app start up DI modules will get initialized first so any misconfiguration in module will be visible as soon as the app starts rather than after some days or time. It is also possible to load modules incrementally but if we stick to the spirit of DI by limiting the module loading before initializing the application logic, we can successfully isolate the bad bindings to the start of the app. But if we configure it as service locator anti pattern then those bad bindings will surely be a surprise.

Comment: @RichardTingle I understand that it will never be similar to the safety net provided by the compiler but DI as a tool used correctly as told in the box then those runtime errors are limited to the app initialization. Then we can look the app initialization as a sort of compilation phase for DI modules. In my experience most of the time if the app starts then there wont be bad bindings or incorrect references in it. 
PS - I've been using NInject with C#

Comment: @RichardTingle - I agree with you, but it's a trade-off in order to obtain loosely coupled, thus testable code. And as k4vin said, missing dependencies are found at initialization, and using interfaces will still help with compile time errors.

Comment: I would add "Hard to keep code clean" in your list. You never know if you can delete a registration before you extensively test the code without it.

Answer (score 42):

I don't think such a list exists, however try to read those articles:

- [**DI can obscure the code (if you're not working with a good IDE)**](http://dlinsin.blogspot.com/2009/11/dependency-injection-obscures-your-code.html)
- [**Misusing IoC can lead to bad code according to Uncle Bob.**](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/22/rejecting-dependency-injection-inversion.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+AyendeRahien+%28Ayende+@+Rahien%29)
- [**Need to look out for over-engineering and creating unnecessary versatility.**](http://devhawk.net/2009/07/17/The+Texas+Dependency+Injection+Massacre.aspx)

Comment: I am curious, when someone asks for wonsides, why answers in a spirit "there aren't any" get upvoted and those which contain some information related to the question not?

Comment: -1 because I'm not looking for a link collection, I'm looking for actual answers: how about summarizing each article's points? Then I'd upvote instead. Note that the articles themselves are quite interesting though it seems the first two are actually debunking negatives of DI?

Comment: I wonder if the most upvoted answer got downvoted as well, because it really doesn't answer the question at all imho:)
Sure I know what you asked and what I answered, I am not asking for upvotes, I am just confused why my answer isn't helping whilst apparently saying DI downside is that it is too cool is helping much.

Answer (score 29):

Code without any DI runs the well-known risk of getting tangled up into [Spaghetti code](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?SpaghettiCode) - some symptoms are that the classes and methods are too large, do too much and cannot be easy changed, broken down, refactored, or tested.

Code with DI used a lot can be [Ravioli code](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?RavioliCode) where each small class is like an individual ravioli nugget - it does one small thing and the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is adhered to, which is good. But looking at classes on their own it's hard to see what the system as a whole does, since this depends on how all these many small parts fit together, which is hard to see. It just looks like a big pile of small things.

By avoiding the spaghetti complexity of big bits of coupled code within a large class, you run the risk of another kind of complexity, where there are lots of simple little classes and the interactions between them are complex.

I don't think that this is a fatal downside - DI is still very much worthwhile. Some degree of ravioli style with small classes that do just one thing is probably good. Even in excess, I don't think that it is bad as spaghetti code. But being aware that it can be taken too far is the first step to avoiding it. Follow the links for discussion of how to avoid it.

Comment: Yes, I like that term "ravioli code"; I express it more long-windedly when I talk about the downside of DI.  Still, I can't imagine developing any real framework or application in Java without DI.

Comment: The trick with ravioli code is understanding that, unlike in "spaghetti code", the main code flow doesn't exist in a function - it exists in whatever is wiring together the objects.  That's a thing to *learn*, but once you're accustomed to looking for it, it gets a lot easier.

Answer (score 14):

The illusion that you've decoupled your code just by implementing dependency injection without *actually* decoupling it. I think that's the most dangerous thing about DI.

Answer (score 13):

If you have a home-grown solution, the dependencies are right in your face in the constructor. Or maybe as method parameters which again is not too hard to spot. Though  framework managed dependencies, if taken to the extremes, can begin to appear like magic.

However, having too many dependencies in too many classes is a clear sign that your class structure is screwed up. So in a way dependency injection (home-grown or framework managed) can help bring glaring design issues out that might otherwise be hidden lurking in the dark.

---

To illustrate the second point better, here's an excerpt from [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/07/rethinking-design-patterns.html) ([original source](http://perl.plover.com/yak/design/samples/slide001.html)) which I whole heartedly believe is the fundamental problem in building any system, not just computer systems.

> Suppose you want to design a college campus. You must delegate some of the design to the students and professors, otherwise the Physics building won't work well for the physics people. No architect knows enough about about what physics people need to do it all themselves. But you can't delegate the design of every room to its occupants, because then you'll get a giant pile of rubble.
>
> How can you distribute responsibility for design through all levels of a large hierarchy, while still maintaining consistency and harmony of overall design? This is the architectural design problem Alexander is trying to solve, but it's also a fundamental problem of computer systems development.

Does DI solve this problem? **No**. But it does help you see clearly if you're trying to delegate the responsibility of designing every room to its occupants.

Answer (score 13):

One thing that makes me squirm a little with DI is the assumption that all injected objects are *cheap to instantiate* and *produce no side effects* -OR- the dependency is used so frequently that it outweighs any associated instantiation cost.

Where this is can be significant is when a dependency is not *frequently* used within a consuming class; such as something like an `IExceptionLogHandlerService`.  Obviously, a service like this is invoked (hopefully :)) rarely within the class - presumably only on exceptions needing to be logged; yet the *canonical constructor-injection pattern*...

```vbnet
Public Class MyClass
    Private ReadOnly mExLogHandlerService As IExceptionLogHandlerService

    Public Sub New(exLogHandlerService As IExceptionLogHandlerService)
        Me.mExLogHandlerService = exLogHandlerService
    End Sub

    ' ...
End Class
```

...requires that a "live" instance of this service be provided, damned the cost/side-effects required to get it there.  Not that it likely would, but what if constructing this dependency instance involved a service/database hit, or configuration file look-ups, or locked a resource until disposed of?  If this service was instead constructed as-needed, service-located, or factory-generated (all having problems their own), then you would be taking the construction cost only when necessary.

Now, it is a generally accepted software design principle that constructing an object *is* cheap and *doesn't* produce side-effects.  And while that's a nice notion, it isn't always the case.  Using typical constructor-injection however basically demands that this is the case.  Meaning when you create an implementation of a dependency, you have to design it with DI in mind.  Maybe you would have made object-construction more costly to obtain benefits elsewhere, but if this implementation is going to be injected, it will likely force you to reconsider that design.

By the way, certain techniques can mitigate this exact issue by allowing lazy-loading of injected dependencies, e.g., providing a class a `Lazy<IService>` instance as the dependency.  This would change your dependent objects' constructors and make then even more cognizant of implementation details such as object construction expense, which is arguably not desirable either.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I don't think its fair to say "when you create an implementation of a dependency, you have to design it with DI in mind" - I think a more accurate statement would be "DI works best when used with classes that are implemented with best practices regarding instantiation cost and a lack of side effects or failure modes during construction".  Worst case, you could always inject a lazy proxy implementation that defers allocation of the real object until first use.

Comment: Any modern IoC container will allow you to specify an object's lifetime for a specific abstract type/interface (always unique, singleton, http scoped, etc). You can also provide a factory method/delegate to instantiate it lazily using Func<T> or Lazy<T>.

Comment: Spot on. Instantiating dependencies unnecessarily costs memory. I normally utilize "lazy-loading" with getters that only instantiate a class when called upon. You can provide default a constructor without parameters as well as subsequent constructors that accept instantiated dependencies. In the first case, a class implementing IErrorLogger, for example, is only instantiated with `this.errorLogger.WriteError(ex)` when an error occurs in a try/catch statement.

Answer (score 12):

This is more of a nitpick. But one of the downsides of dependency injection is that it makes it a little harder for development tools to reason about and navigate code.

Specifically, if you Control-Click/Command-Click on a method invocation in code, it'll take you to the method declaration on an interface instead of the concrete implementation.

This is really more of a downside of loosely coupled code (code that's designed by interface), and applies even if you don't use dependency injection (i.e., even if you simply use factories). But the advent of dependency injection is what really encouraged loosely coupled code to the masses, so I thought I'd mention it.

Also, the benefits of loosely coupled code far outweigh this, thus I call it a nitpick. Though I've worked long enough to know that this is the sort of push-back you may get if you attempt to introduce dependency injection.

In fact, I'd venture to guess that for every "downside" you can find for dependency injection, you'll find many upsides that far outweigh it.

Comment: Ctrl-shift-B with resharper takes you the implementation

Comment: But then again would we not (in an ideal world) have at least 2 implementations of everything, i.e. at least one real implementation  and a mock one for unit testing ;-)

Comment: In Eclipse if you hold Ctrl and hover over method invocation code it will show you a menu to open either the Declaration or Implementation.

Comment: If you're at the interface definition, highlight the method name and strike Ctrl+T to bring up the type hierarchy for that method--you'll see every implementor of that method in a type hierarchy tree.

Answer (score 12):

*Constructor-based* dependency injection (without the aid of magical "frameworks") is a clean and beneficial way to structure OO code. In the best codebases I've seen, over years spent with other ex-colleagues of Martin Fowler, I started to notice that most good classes written this way end up having a single `doSomething` method.

The major downside, then, is that once you realise it's all just a kludgy long-handed OO way of writing closures as classes in order to get the benefits of functional programming, your motivation to write OO code can quickly evaporate.

Comment: Problem with constructor-based is that you'll always need to add more constructor args...

Comment: Haha. If you do that too much you will soon see that your code is crappy and you will refactor it. Besides, ctrl-f6 ain't that hard.

Comment: And of course the reverse is also true: it's all just a kludgy long-handed functional way of writing classes as closures in order to get the benefits of OO programming

Comment: Many years ago I built an object system using closures in Perl, so I get what you're saying, but encapsulating data isn't a *unique* benefit of OO programming, so it's not clear what these beneficial features of OO are which would be comparably kludgy and long-handed to obtain in a functional language.

Answer (score 10):

I find that constructor injection can lead to big ugly constructors, (and I use it throughout my codebase - perhaps my objects are too granular?).  Also, sometimes with constructor injection I end up with horrible circular dependencies (although this is very rare), so you may find yourself having to have some kind of ready state lifecycle with several rounds of dependency injection in a more complex system.

However, I favour construtor injection over  setter injection because once my object is constructed, then I know without a doubt what state it is in, whether it is in a unit test environment or loaded up in some IOC container.  Which, in a roundabout sort of way, is saying what I feel is the main drawback with setter injection.

(as a sidenote, I do find the whole topic quite "religious", but your mileage will vary with the level of technical zealotry in your dev team!)

Comment: If you have big ugly constructors, may be your classes are to big and you just have to much dependencies?

Comment: That is certainly a possibility I'm willing to entertain!...Sadly, I don't have a team I can do peer reviews with though. *violins play softly in the background, and then screen fades to black...*

Comment: As Mark Seeman sad above "It can be dangerous for your career" ...

Comment: I had no clue background narrations could be so expressive here :P

Comment: @Robert I'm trying to find the quote, where above did he say that?

Comment: @Robert, a service can be a container class, so yes that can be big, but is the right way to implement. if thats a service that must handle a lot of things, yes you will have to put a lot of dependencies in the constructor. its just a fact of life :-)

Comment: Re *"big ugly constructors"*: That is also the impression one gets from tutorials.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using DI without an [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) container, the biggest downside is you quickly see how many dependencies your code actually has and how tightly coupled everything really is.  ("But I thought it was a good design!")  The natural progression is to move towards an IoC container which can take a little bit of time to learn and implement (not nearly as bad as the WPF learning curve, but it's not free either).  The final downside is some developers will begin to write honest to goodness unit tests and it will take them time to figure it out.  Devs who could previously crank something out in half a day will suddenly spend two days trying to figure out how to mock all of their dependencies.

Similar to [Mark Seemann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407540/what-are-the-downsides-to-using-dependency-injection/2407614#2407614) (now deleted; only visible with more than 10,000 reputation points), the bottom line is that you spend time becoming a better developer rather than hacking bits of code together and tossing it out the door/into production.  Which would your business rather have?  Only you can answer that.

Comment: Good point. That is poor quality/fast delivery vs good quality/slow delivery. The downside? DI is not magic, expecting it to be is the downside.

Answer (score 5):

Code readability. You'll not be able to easily figure out the code flow since the dependencies are hidden in XML files.

Comment: You don't need to use XML configuration files for dependency injection - choose a DI container which supports configuration in code.

Comment: Dependency injection doesn't necessarily imply XML files. It seems like this may still be the case in Java, but in .NET we abandonded this coupling years ago.

Comment: Or don't use a DI container at all.

Comment: if you know the code is using DI, you can easily assume who sets the dependencies.

Comment: In Java, Google's Guice doesn't need XML files for example.

Answer (score 5):

DI is a technique or a pattern and not related to any framework. You can wire up your dependencies manually. DI helps you with SR (Single responsibility) and SoC (separation of concerns). DI leads to a better design. From my point of view and experience **there are no downsides**. Like with any other pattern you can get it wrong or misuse it (but what is in the case of DI quite hard).

If you introduce DI as principle to a legacy application, using a framework - the single biggest mistake you can do is to misuse it as a Service-Locater. DI+Framework itself is great and just made things better everywhere I saw it! From organizational standpoint, there are the common problems with every new process, technique, pattern, ...:

- You have to train you team
- You have to change your application (which include risks)

In general you have to **invest time and money**, beside that, there a no downsides, really!

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the supposed benefits of a statically-typed language diminish significantly when you're constantly employing techniques to work around the static typing. One large Java shop I just interviewed at was mapping out their build dependencies with static code analysis...which had to parse all the Spring files in order to be effective.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- They require extra tool support to check that the configuration is valid.

For example, IntelliJ (commercial edition) has support for checking the validity of a Spring configuration, and will flag up errors such as type violations in the configuration.  Without that kind of tool support, you can't check whether the configuration is valid before  running tests.

This is one reason why the 'cake' pattern (as it's known to the Scala community) is a good idea: the wiring between components can be checked by the type checker.  You don't have that benefit with annotations or XML.

- It makes global static analysis of programs very difficult.

Frameworks like Spring or Guice make it difficult to determine statically what the object graph created by the container will look like.  Although they create an object graph when the container is started up, they don't provide useful APIs that describe the object graph that /would/ be created.

Comment: This is absolute bull. Dependency injection is a concept, it does not require a fricken framework. All you need is new. Ditch spring and all that crap, then your tools will work just fine, plus you will be able to refactor your code much more better.

Comment: True, good point.  I should've been more clear that I was talking about problems with DI frameworks and not the pattern.  It's possible I missed the clarification to the question when I answered (assuming it was there at the time).

Comment: Ah. In which case I happily retract my annoyance. apologies.

Answer (score 1):

It can increase app startup time because IoC container should resolve dependencies in a proper way and it sometimes requires to make several iterations.

Comment: Just to give a figure, a DI container should resolve multiple thousands dependencies per second. (http://www.codinginstinct.com/2008/05/ioc-container-benchmark-rerevisted.html)  DI containers allow deferred instantiation. Performance should (even in huge applications) not be a problem. Or at least performance problem should be addressable and not be a reason to decide against IoC and its frameworks.