# Is the DI pattern limiting wrt expensive object creation coupled with infrequent dependency usage?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, language-agnostic, dependency-injection

I'm having a hard time getting my head around what seems like an obvious pattern problem/limitation when it comes to typical constructor dependency injection.  For example purposes, lets say I have an ASP.NET MVC3 controller that looks like:

```vb
Public Class MyController
    Inherits Controller

    Private ReadOnly mServiceA As IServiceA
    Private ReadOnly mServiceB As IServiceB
    Private ReadOnly mServiceC As IServiceC

    Public Sub New(serviceA As IServiceA, serviceB As IServiceB, serviceC As IServiceC)
        Me.mServiceA = serviceA
        Me.mServiceB = serviceB
        Me.mServiceC = serviceC
    End Sub

    Public Function ActionA() As ActionResult
        ' Do something with Me.mServiceA and Me.mServiceB
    End Function

    Public Function ActionB() As ActionResult
        ' Do something with Me.mServiceB and Me.mServiceC
    End Function
End Class
```

The thing I'm having a hard time getting over is the fact that the DI container was asked to instantiate *all three dependencies* when at any given time only a subset of the dependencies may be required by the action methods on this controller.

It's seems assumed that object construction is dirt-cheep and there are no side effects from object construction OR *all dependencies are consistently utilized*.  What if object construction wasn't cheep or there were side effects?  For example, if constructing `IServiceA` involved opening a connection or allocating other significant resources, then that would be completely wasted time/resources when `ActionB` is called.

If these action methods used a service location pattern (or other similar pattern), then there would never be the chance to unnecessarily construct an object instance that will go unused, of course using this pattern has other issues attached making it unattractive.

Does using the canonical *constructor injection + interfaces* pattern of DI basically lock the developer into a "limitation" of sorts that implementations of the dependency must be cheep to instantiate or the instance must be significantly utilized?  I know all patterns have their pros and cons, is this just one of DI's cons?  I've never seen it mentioned before, which I find curious.

Comment: There is a related [SO post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407540/what-are-the-downsides-to-using-dependency-injection) asking for the "downsides" of DI, and I didn't see this listed, which is what is prompting me to ask.  Makes me concerned I'm missing something.

Comment: I added the VB tag so that your code would be colored correctly.  No worries that you removed it, but I wanted to let you know why.  :)

Comment: @Phil Sandler Ah, I was unaware that was what triggered that, thanks for the consideration and your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a lot of fields that aren't being used by every member this means that the class' **cohesion is low**. This is a general programming concept - **Constructor Injection just makes it more visible**. It's usually a pretty good indicator that the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is being violated.

If that's the case then refactor (e.g. to [Facade Services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringToAggregateServices.aspx)).

[You don't have to worry about performance when creating object graphs](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/ComposeObjectGraphsWithConfidence.aspx).

When it comes to side effects, (DI) [constructors should be simple and not have side effects](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsShouldBeSimple.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't trying to imply that we were in this state.  I was going under the assumption that we are already at good granularity in both the consuming code and in what the dependency provides.  For example, what if your dependency was something like an `IExceptionLoggerService`, you may have that referenced in many methods, but _hopefully_ it never is called upon. When `IExceptionLoggerService` is built, it HAS to know that it will be DIed, so a dev doesn't lock a file or hit a service at construction.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, there should be no major costs or side effects of object construction.  This is a general statement that I believe applies to most (not all) objects, but is especially true for services that you would inject via DI.  In other words, constructing a service class automatically makes a database/service call, or changes the state of your system in a way that would have side effects is (at least) a code smell.

Regarding instances that go unused: it's hard to create a system that has perfect utilization of instances within dependent classes, regardless of whether you use DI or not.  I'm not sure achieving this is very important, as long as you are adhering to the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  If you find that your class has too many services injected, or that utilization is *really* uneven, it might be a sign that your class is doing too much and needs to be split into two or more smaller classes with more focused responsibilities.

Comment: "*... but is especially true for services that you would inject via DI.*"  So you are confirming that indeed, going down a constructor-injection path like this does make the assumption that the general-accepted principle that object construction shall be cheep & have no side effects is honored.  I agree that unused instances can be virtually ignored (wrt *this* topic) *if* the object construction rules (cheep & safe) holds true.

Comment: I would say it makes that assumption, yes, but that assumption would ideally be implicit in good design anyway, at least for the types of services you would want to inject.

Comment: +1 with respect to the SRP. Another way to put it is that if you don't use a lot of the dependencies, the class has too low cohesion.

Answer (score 2):

No you are not tied to the limitations you have listed. As of .net 4 you do have [Lazy(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) at your disposal, which will allow you to defer instantiation of your dependencies until required.

It is not assumed that object construction is dirt-cheap and consequently [some](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lazy%20Exports) DI containers support `Lazy(Of T)` out of the box. Whilst Unity 2.0 supports lazy initialization out of the box through [automatic factories](http://www.machinaaurum.com.br/blog/post/Automatic-Factories-With-Unity-20.aspx), there is a good article [here](http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2010/05/lazy-and-ienumerable-support-comes-to.html) on an extension supporting  `Lazy(Of T)` the author has on [MSDN](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=PierreCode&ReleaseId=4357).

Comment: This is good to know, thanks for the links.  I didn't see anything in here though about constructor injection taking an interface, which is what my question was pointing out.  Using *constructor injection* with interfaces, you still seem to be under the thumb of the listed limitations/assumptions, no?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. Both the MEF and Unity examples show injection of Lazy(Of Interface). Is your concern they are only showing property injection, as the same would apply to constructor injection. Or is it that you want to avoid changing your constructor parameters to Lazy<IService*>? If the latter then likely yes, but would there be a reason not to? What DI framework are you using?

Comment: I was intending to keep this language/framework independent and focus more on the pattern's (potential) notable assumption based on how the pattern is *typically presented to new practitioners*. I agree that using a `Lazy<IService>` approach changes the game and opens the door to many (wonderful) things mitigating limitations like these.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your controller a singleton though? That is the normal way to do it in Java. There is only one instance created. Also you could split the controller into multiple controllers if the roles of the actions is so distinct.

Comment: Agreed, limiting a controller's responsibility is key, but this can only go so far -- you wouldn't want to end up with one method per controller :)  Granularity of the service and the consuming class is a factor, but my question is making the assumption that they are already as granular as appropriate.

Comment: "Isn't your controller a singleton though?"  No, it is not.  It is instantiated at the beginning of each request and disposed at the end of it.