# Using Spring.Net for dynamically creating objects

Tags: c#, .net, spring, inversion-of-control, spring.net

*I am not an expert on spring or IoC - I would like to have my client app "select" different implementations of an interface based on some conditions.

I believe Spring (or other IoC containers) allow doing this, however all examples show that the concrete class is configured in some configuration file, which is not what i am after.

I would like to (somehow) allow the container to decide which implementation to choose from (based on some conditions and a given set of classes to select from).

Is this possible? ( i am pretty sure it is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [factory class](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-class-static-factory-method) (it could be static or instance factory).

Comment: What is the benefit of using Spring then, if i need to provide my own Factory (i could write the same thing without Spring)

Comment: If you are only using spring as a factory to get objects from, you are not taking full advantage of the capabilities of the spring container, such as interception. You might be interested in reading these questions [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557742/dependency-injection-vs-factory-pattern) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405/why-do-i-need-an-ioc-container-as-opposed-to-straightforward-di-code) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407540/what-are-the-downsides-to-using-dependency-injection).