# How to make stubs and spies on methods which import from a package?

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, jestjs, stub

I am a JavaScript and Python developer. Here is a unit testing code snippet using [jestjs](https://jestjs.io/) testing framework:

`index.ts`:

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

export class OsEnvFetcher {
  constructor() {
    const output = dotenv.config();
    if (output.error) {
      console.log('Error loading .env file');
      process.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { OsEnvFetcher } from './';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

describe('OsEnvFetcher', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mOutput = { error: new Error('parsed failure') };
    jest.spyOn(dotenv, 'config').mockReturnValueOnce(mOutput);
    const errorLogSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const exitStub = jest.spyOn(process, 'exit').mockImplementation();
    new OsEnvFetcher();
    expect(dotenv.config).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(errorLogSpy).toBeCalledWith('Error loading .env file');
    expect(exitStub).toBeCalledWith(1);
  });
});
```

The outcome for the unit testing:

```
 PASS  stackoverflow/todo/index.test.ts (11.08s)
  OsEnvFetcher
    ✓ should pass (32ms)

  console.log
    Error loading .env file

      at CustomConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 6                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.467s
```

The test method in the example is very common in a js project using [Arrange, Act, Assert](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Arrange-Act-Assert) pattern. Due to the `dotenv.config()` method will do some file system I/O operations, it has a side-effect. So we will make a stub or mock for it. In this way, our unit tests have no side effects and are tested in an isolated environment.

The same applies to python. We can use [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) mock object library to do the same thing. I'm very comfortable with these unit testing approaches.

Now, I switch to go, try to do the same thing. Code here:

`osEnvFetcher.go`

```golang
package util

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

var godotenvLoad = godotenv.Load

type EnvFetcher interface {
    Getenv(key string) string
}

type osEnvFetcher struct {}

func NewOsEnvFetcher() *osEnvFetcher {
    err := godotenvLoad()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
    }
    return &osEnvFetcher{}
}

func (f *osEnvFetcher) Getenv(key string) string {
    return os.Getenv(key)
}
```

`osEnvFetcher_test.go`:

```golang
package util

import (
    "testing"
    "fmt"
)

func TestOsEnvFetcher(t *testing.T) {
    old := godotenvLoad
    defer func() { godotenvLoad = old }()
    godotenvLoad = func() error {
        return 
    }
    osEnvFetcher := NewOsEnvFetcher()
    port := osEnvFetcher.Getenv("PORT")
    fmt.Println(port)
}
```

The test case is not finished. I'm not sure how should I mock, stub, or spy `godotenv.Load` method(Equivalent to `dotenv.config()`) and `log.Fatal` method? I found this mock package - [mock](https://github.com/golang/mock). But [godotenv](https://github.com/joho/godotenv) package has no interface, it's composed by functions.

I'm looking for some ways like [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) and [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname).Or, like [stubs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/) and [spies](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v9.0.2/spies/) of [sinonjs](https://sinonjs.org/). Or, like [spyOn](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#spyOn) of [jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/index.html). These methods can cover almost any test scenario.  No matter use DI or import modules directly.

I saw some ways, but they all have their own problems.

E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41661462/6463558.

What about I need to stub ten methods which have side-effect? I need to assign these methods of a package ​​to 10 variables and replace them with the mocked version in test cases ten times before running the test. It's non-scalable. Maybe I can create a `__mocks__` directory and put all the mocked version object in it. So that I can use them in all test files.

Use Dependency Injection is better. In this way we can pass the mocked objects to the function/method. But some scenarios are directly importing the packages and use the methods of packages(3rd or built-in standard library). This is also the scenario in my question. I think this scenario is inevitable and will definitely appear on a certain layer of the code.

I can handle this scenario easily using `jestjs`, E.g.

`util.js`,

```
exports.resolveAddress = function(addr) {
  // ...
  const data = exports.parseJSON(json);
  return data;
}
exports.parseJSON = function(json) {}
```

`main.js`:

```js
// import util module directly rather than using Dependency Injection
import util from './util';
function main() {
  return util.resolveAddress();
}
```

`main.test.js`:

```js
import util from './util';
const mJson = 'mocked json data';
jest.spyOn(util, 'parseJSON').mockReturnValueOnce(mJson)
const actual = main()
expect(actual).toBe('mocked json data');
```

I directly imports `util` module and mock `util.parseJSON` method and its returned value. I am not sure if Go's package can do this. For now, these issues are **Arrange** issues.

Besides, I also need to check the methods are indeed called to make sure the code logics and branches are correct. (E.g. the `.toBeCalledWith()` method using `jestjs`). This is **Assert** issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You certainly can't mock/stub/etc. `log.Fatal`, that's *a* function, can't be tampered with, it's body can't be switched with some other function body. `godotenvLoad`, on the other hand, is just a variable, you can replace its value with anything you want as long as its type matches the variable's type.

Comment: In Go mocking is uncommon while fakes and stubs are the normal way to test stuff which has dependencies. This often results in much cleaner tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19168875/6463558):

`osEnvFetcher.go`:

```golang
package util

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

var godotenvLoad = godotenv.Load
var logFatal = log.Fatal

type EnvFetcher interface {
    Getenv(key string) string
}

type osEnvFetcher struct {}

func NewOsEnvFetcher() *osEnvFetcher {
    err := godotenvLoad()
    if err != nil {
        logFatal("Error loading .env file")
    }
    return &osEnvFetcher{}
}

func (f *osEnvFetcher) Getenv(key string) string {
    return os.Getenv(key)
}
```

`osEnvFetcher_test.go`:

```golang
package util

import (
    "testing"
    "errors"
)


func mockRestore(oGodotenvLoad func(...string) error, oLogFatal func(v ...interface{})) {
    godotenvLoad = oGodotenvLoad
    logFatal = oLogFatal
}

func TestOsEnvFetcher(t *testing.T) {
    // Arrange
    oGodotenvLoad := godotenvLoad
    oLogFatal := logFatal
    defer mockRestore(oGodotenvLoad, oLogFatal)
    var godotenvLoadCalled = false
    godotenvLoad = func(...string) error {
        godotenvLoadCalled = true
        return errors.New("parsed failure")
    }
    var logFatalCalled = false
    var logFatalCalledWith interface{}
    logFatal = func(v ...interface{}) {
        logFatalCalled = true
        logFatalCalledWith = v[0]
    }
    // Act
    NewOsEnvFetcher()
    // Assert
    if !godotenvLoadCalled {
        t.Errorf("godotenv.Load should be called")
    }
    if !logFatalCalled {
        t.Errorf("log.Fatal should be called")
    }
    if logFatalCalledWith != "Error loading .env file" {
        t.Errorf("log.Fatal should be called with: %s", logFatalCalledWith)
    }
}
```

The outcome with coverage for the test:

```
☁  util [master] ⚡  go test -v -coverprofile cover.out
=== RUN   TestOsEnvFetcher
--- PASS: TestOsEnvFetcher (0.00s)
PASS
coverage: 80.0% of statements
```

coverage html reporter:

[image]