# Stubbing time.Now() during tests golang?

Tags: go, time, stubbing, go-testing

I'm following another answer here: [Is there an easy way to stub out time.Now() globally during test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970265/is-there-an-easy-way-to-stub-out-time-now-globally-during-test/41661462#41661462)

#### So I have this file where I do something like:

```
var timeNow = time.Now

func GenerateTimestamp() int64 {
    now := timeNow() // current local time
    sec := now.Unix() // number of seconds since January 1, 1970 UTC

    return sec // int 64
}
```

#### We use GenerateTimestamp() in another function

```
func AddTs() {
    // Some if check, use GenerateTimestamp() here
}
```

---

#### Now on my test file, I am doing something like:

```
    now := time.Now()
    timeNow = func() int64 {
        // fmt.Println("looking for this", now.Unix())
        return now.Unix()
    }
```

I am getting this error `cannot use func literal (type func() int64) as type func() time.Time in assignment`. I need to be able to return an int64 type (which my original function returns), how can I get around this?

Feel free to point me to docs, I am a Go newbie!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`time.Now()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Now) is a function that returns a value of type [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time):

```
func Now() Time
```

So the type of `timeNow` is a function of this type: `func() time.Time`. This is obviously different than `func() int64`.

You have to return a `time.Time` value. If you want to return a `time.Time` value that represents a specific unix time, you may use the [`time.Unix()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix) function to get that value, e.g.

```
unixsec := int64(1605139200) // This is 2020-11-12 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

timeNow = func() time.Time {
    return time.Unix(unixsec, 0)
}
```

If you want to return a specific date-time, you may use [`time.Date()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Date), e.g.:

```
timeNow = func() time.Time {
    return time.Date(2020, 11, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
}
```

Of course you are not limited to always return the same time instant. You can return incrementing time values on each call, e.g.:

```
unixsec := int64(1605139200) // This is 2020-11-12 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

timeNow = func() time.Time {
    unixsec++ // Increment number of seconds by 1
    return time.Unix(unixsec, 0)
}
```

This `timeNow` function will return a time value that is always incremented by 1 second (compared to the value returned by the previous call).

Comment: Thanks for this response! This was super helpful :)