# Is it OK to share common details between view models in a static class?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton, viewmodel, mvvmcross

I am experimenting with MvvmCross view models and in my app they are shared not just between different platforms having similar layout structure, but also between applications where the information is presented differently depending on the app's form factor. For example, an iPad app may show customer list and selected customer details on a same page, while iPhone app splits them between different pages. MvvmCross supports all such scenarios so it's quite straightforward to share common view model set between all these applications.

There are however cases when it's convenient to share same details across multiple view models. For example, different views may show recent twitter messages, stock quote updates etc. Or some global user settings (user name, recent login time etc.) For the time being I have placed them in a singleton class AppState that is inherited from MvxNotifyPropertyChanged. All view models have property AppState to access shared app state, so any view can bind its controls to AppState.. This works also for design-time models.

I've tested on a couple of platforms (didn't try non-Windows platforms yet), and it works as expected. But I didn't test lifetime scenarios, such as tombstoning/dehydration. Basically I have some portions on my views bound to properties of a singleton. Are there any caveats related to a view model lifetime?

In addition, if use of such singletons is acceptable, I can either use [singleton pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) or MvvmCross dependency injection (MvxResolve). Technically it will be the same, so is there any advantage of either methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If static sharing works for you and your app, that's great.

There's no specific reason I can think of why this should make your objects harder to use in different lifecycle situations.

The main reasons why `static`s are 'frowned upon' are architectural reasons - `static`s lead to tightly coupled code which is less testable and which is (IMHO) harder to maintain and reuse in the longer term.

If your app doesn't care about these things - which may be the case - then static singletons may be a great way to build your app - and may even make the code simpler to follow for others.

There are plenty of other questions about this type of area, like:

- [What are the downsides to using Dependency Injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407540/what-are-the-downsides-to-using-dependency-injection) - with the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2407614/373321
- [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)
- [Why do I need an IoC container as opposed to straightforward DI code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405/why-do-i-need-an-ioc-container-as-opposed-to-straightforward-di-code?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of implications for tests, but in this case I want my tests to validate actual singleton values, so I keep AppState outside mocking. I was more concerned about anything related to singleton lifetime on some particular mobile platform.
Thanks for the answer!